# IsInArray Function VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I found a function that returns me a true/false result if a certain string, number or date is in an array. I slightly modified it so it gives me a number instead (if the value is in the array, it gives me the coordinate, otherwise it gives me -1).

```
Public Function IsInArray2(DateToBeFound As Date, arr As Variant) As Long
 Dim position As Long
 IsInArray2 = -1

 For position = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(position) = DateToBeFound Then
        IsInArray2 = position
        Exit For
    End If
 Next

End Function
```

I am trying to use this function to check if a date is in an array. If it is, I can use the coordinate for further calculations in my code.

**Problem:** For some reason, I am getting and error (subscript out of range) in the line:

```
If arr(position) = DateToBeFound Then
```

I already tried changing the array reference, changing date to number, to string, and tried redim the array in regard to the maximum amount of items it has, still, the error persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: `arr(position,1)` ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also already tried that, same result. In either way, since the array has only one dimension, would it be necessary to state in which dimension to look?

Comment: Did you construct your array manually or load it from a range? how are you passing it to your function? try adding `Debug.Print LBound(arr, 1):Debug.Print UBound(arr, 1):Debug.Print position` at the start of your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load an array directly from a range on a sheet :

i.e `Arr=Sheets(1).Range("A1:B2").Value`

the array is in 2 dimensions!

So you need to use `Arr(position,1)`! ;)

Comment: I did not know it entered as 2D. I have tried adding the one before posting the question, but it did not work. Just restarted the file and tried again, it works. I do not fathom this sorcery, lol.

Answer (score 2):

"vertical range" (more than one row) results in 2D array, but `For Each` loop can be used (not tested):

```
Public Function IndexOf(arr, value) As Long
    Dim v: IndexOf = 0        
    For Each v in arr
        If v = value Then Exit For
        IndexOf = IndexOf + 1
    Next
    IndexOf = -1 ' not found
End Function
```

For non-date or currency types:

```
Public Function IndexOf(arr, value) As Long
    Dim v: v = Application.Match(arr, value, 0)
    IndexOf = IIf(IsError(v), -1, v)
End Function
```